# How can I loop through html controls in ASP.NET page with No "runat=server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, codeblocks, runatserver, htmlcontrols

How can I loop through html controls inside an ASPX page which don't have `"runat=server"` attribute?
Because of using code blocks and dynamic variables on them I cannot add the attribute:

```
<input lang='<%= language.ID %>' checked='<%= check(x) %>' />
```

Comment: Why do you need to access those controls? to get the values, to add attributes?

Comment: Without "runat=server" there is no control, it is just plain text, as far as Asp.net is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I loop through html controls inside an ASPX page which don't have "runat=server" ...*

Depends on what you want you're looking to do.

- As the other answers have stated, end of the day, it's all HTML and therefore a `Form` will `submit` (by default an `HTTP POST` for `ASP.Net Web Forms` hence `Postback`) somewhere and you can loop through [`HttpRequest.Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.form?view=netframework-4.7) on the server side (aka "code-behind").
- As stated, in the end everything renders as a standard HTML element that you can provide `id` or `class` and "loop" through them and do what you want on the *front end*.

  Here's a trivial example:

```js
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('inputs');    
var count = eles.length;
var str = "there are " + count + " elements:<br>";
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  str = str + "name: " + eles[i].name + " id: " + eles[i].id + "<br>";
}

var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML= str;
```

```html
<input name="foo" lang='some-server-generated-string-1' id="ele1" class="inputs" />
<input name="bar" lang='some-server-generated-string-2' id="ele2" class="inputs" />
<p id="result"></p>
```

Hth.